# Mongodb creating alias in a query

Tags: mongodb

What is the mongodb's equivalent to this query:

> SELECT "foo" as bar, `id` as "spec" from tablename

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751835/how-to-get-modified-json-output-from-mongodb-node-js-mongoose/14752107#14752107

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible to create new field with given name and value taken from another field with $project:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  title: "abc123",
  isbn: "0001122223334",
  author: { last: "zzz", first: "aaa" },
  copies: 5
}
```

The following $project stage adds the new fields isbn, lastName, and copiesSold:

```
db.books.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            title: 1,
            isbn: {
               prefix: { $substr: [ "$isbn", 0, 3 ] },
               group: { $substr: [ "$isbn", 3, 2 ] },
               publisher: { $substr: [ "$isbn", 5, 4 ] },
               title: { $substr: [ "$isbn", 9, 3 ] },
               checkDigit: { $substr: [ "$isbn", 12, 1] }
            },
            lastName: "$author.last",
            copiesSold: "$copies"
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the project stage does allow "aliases" for fields. See user1735921 's answer for an example of how to project w/o modifying the original field value

Comment: If I created an index for "title" and in $project I changed "title" to "leTitle", will sorting "leTitle" use the index for "title"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use any operator like toUpper or toLower or concat or any other operator you feel like which you think you can work on and create an alias.

Example:
In the following example created_time is a field in the collection.
(I am not good with syntax so you can correct it, but this is the approach)

```
{$project {
"ALIAS_one" : {"$concat" : "$created_time"},
"ALIAS_two" : {"$concat" : "$created_time"},
"ALIAS_three" : {"$concat" : "$created_time"}
}}
```

So using an operator in that fashion you can create as many as aliases as your like.

Comment: interesting. I don't believe that the aggregation pipeline was around back when this question was asked. I would point out that $concat could be used w/o manipulating the value

Comment: yeah concat would be better, anyways I was just giving an example of a possible way which I thought of...edited my post. Although Andrey has already posted the native syntax which is there already in MongoDB. Its just another possible way, sometimes it comes in handy when writing complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, maybe help

### database data

```
{ "_id" : "5ab0f445edf197158835be63", "userid" : "5aaf15c28264ee17fe869ad8", "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-03-21T07:04:41.735Z") }
{ "_id" : "5ab0f445edf197158835be64", "userid" : "5aaf15c28264ee17fe869ad8", "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-02-20T12:31:08.896Z") }
{ "_id" : "5ab0f445edf197158835be65", "userid" : "5aaf15c28264ee17fe869ad7", "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-02-20T02:31:08.896Z") }
```

### mongo command

```
db.zhb_test.aggregate(
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m",
                date: "$lastmodified"
            }
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "month": "$_id",
        count: 1,
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```

### result

```
{ "count" : 2, "month" : "2018-02" }
{ "count" : 1, "month" : "2018-03" }
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of research. Thank you.