# How to get modified json output from MongoDB + Node.js + Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider my collection is store as follows in **MongoDB**:

```
  { 
    _id: 'Unique_Value',
    FieldMONGO1: 'ngfn',
    FieldMONGO2: { SomeKey: ['val1','val2','val...']  },
  }
```

When I retrieve using find method on Model Instance of Mongoose. I get the following **JSON output**:

```
  { 
    _id: 'Unique_Value',
    FieldMONGO1: 'NAME_value',
    FieldMONGO2: { SomeKey: ['val1','val2','val...']  },
  }
```

Both are exactly same.

**Question:** Is there any way so that I can change the field names like `FieldMONGO1` to `FirstName`, `FieldMONGO2` to `NewName` & `_id` to `IdentityNo`?

So that my output will be something like this:

```
  { 
    IdentityNo: 'Unique_Value',
    FirstName: 'ngfn',
    NewName: { SomeKey: []  },
  }
```

**Know Solution:** Is to get the JSON output as is and then change field (attribute) name in Node.js code. But here the problem is, it becomes a blocking code. Which can create overhead on server if huge data is requested.

Could anyone help me out in find out some efficient way of doing the same?

Advance Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093441/mongodb-creating-alias-in-a-query

Comment: Why are you using generic field names like `FieldMONGO1` in your docs?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Just for the sake of better understanding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out `Virtuals` in [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

check out the example in the reference link.

if you tweak like

```
urSchema.virtual('FirstName').get(function () {
  return this.FieldMONGO1;
});
```

you can do it.

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363513/mongoose-mongodb-alias-id-field) on SO.

Comment: If have some solution without mongoose as well, let me know.. Thanks for nice answer