# MONGO DB Alias name usage in find query not working

Tags: mongodb, alias

i am using the below command to find records in contacts collection's

```
db.contacts.find({"field1":"1"})
```

the problem is i want to use alias name for field1 as SL.NO

i tried this way and its not working...

```
db.contacts.find({"field :n, as: :SL.NO" : "1"}
```

can anyne help me in this issue?

BTW I am currently using mongo 1.6.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb creating alias in a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093441/mongodb-creating-alias-in-a-query)

Comment: Where are you finding that syntax? Are you using the Mongo shell?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation about this feature? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @ thilo yes...i will point it..

Comment: @noa yes..i am trying to execute it from the mongo shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some drivers like Mongoose support that feature, but there is no such feature in MongoDB itself or the Mongo shell.

Comment: This was accurate at the time of writing. If this answer is obsolete, perhaps instead of downvoting you could comment and provide more information.