# how to change values of a document based on condition in find in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like

```
{
  "name":"A"
   .......
   .......
}
```

In that if name contains 'A' then i need to show Name as "It s movie"
How to achieve this mongo query.

Comment: could you please re-read your question and then fix it so that it's actually asking something?  I have no idea from above what "this mongo query" refers to or what the title has to do with the question.

Comment: actually in that collection i need like
`name LIKE 'A' THEN 'some text ' ELSE '' END AS strMessage`
This is the sql replacement of my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the result set while querying MongoDB (there is no 'AS' aka Alias in MongoDB see: [Mongodb creating alias in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093441/mongodb-creating-alias-in-a-query))

What you can do is run a function in the shell to set strMessage key in your documents.